# Recursion and parallelism in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, parallel-processing

I'm trying to understand how paralleling in Haskell works and I've found following example in Control.Parallel docs.

```
import Control.Parallel

-- Equation for the upper hemisphere of the unit circle

circle :: Double -> Double
circle x = sqrt (abs(1 - x^2))

-- Calculate the area of a right-handed Riemann rectangle

area :: Double -> Double -> Double
area x1 x2 = (x2 - x1) * circle x2

-- Recursively add the areas of the Riemann rectangles

parEstimate :: [Double] -> Double
parEstimate (x:[]) = 0
parEstimate (x:y:[]) = area x y
parEstimate (x:y:xs) =
smaller `par` (larger `pseq` smaller + larger)
  where smaller = area x y
        larger = parEstimate (y:xs)
```

But I couldn't find an explanation of how this recursion works: parEstimate (x:y:xs), cause all examples I've found contains only two arguments.
That's why I cannot find out how to run this function. That's how I do:

```
main = print (parEstimate [1.0, 2.0])
```

but not sure, if it's correct.
Also I would like to implement function calculating definite integral based on this example.

Comment: I'd say you are overthinking this. Does your `main` pass the type checker, runs and prints a result, as you expected from the example? If so, everything is fine.

Comment: "@duplode my code compiles fine, but I can't understand if my output is correct. But the main problem is that I need to calculating definite integral, so without understanding this code it seems difficult.

Comment: All you are doing is printing the result, so the output is exactly as correct as the example code in the documentation is. As for the `(x:y:xs)` pattern, the only difference between that and `(x:xs)` is that you are also giving a name -- `y` -- to the second element of the list (in addition to the first element -- `x` -- and to the tail -- `xs`) so that you can also refer to it in the right side of `=`. Naturally, that only works if the list has at least two elements.

Comment: Also note that the example is not from the `Control.Parallel` docs, but from http://www.stolaf.edu/people/rab/pub/PDC/I15/Pi_Integration_SharedMemory_html/Haskell/Haskell.html

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

The recursion, essentially, is a simple `fold`-like recursion scheme; if this were purely sequential, you might write it as

```
seqEstimate :: [Double] -> Double
seqEstimate (x:[]) = 0
seqEstimate (x:y:[]) = area x y
seqEstimate (x:y:xs) = smaller + larger
    where smaller = area x y
          larger = seqEstimate (y:xs)
```

(In fact, you would probably just use `zipWith` instead: `seqEstimate xs = sum (zipWith area xs (tail xs))`.)

The parallelized version is similar. This time, though, `par` is used to indicate that the left-hand side (`smaller`) can be evaluated in parallel with the right-hand side (`pseq larger (smaller + larger)`). Whether or not the compiler chooses to do so, and regardless of whether `smaller` completes before or after `larger`, the sum of `smaller + larger` will be correctly computed.